# Passing XQuery xml element as external variable to Marklogic via XCC

Tags: xquery, marklogic

We have a fairly simple XQuery and Groovy code as follows.
Xquery code :

```
declare variable $criteria as element(criteria) external ;

<scopedInterventions>{
$criteria/equals/field
}</scopedInterventions>
```

Here is the test code that is trying to invoke it

```
def uri = new URI("xcc://admin:admin@localhost:8001")

def contentSource = ContentSourceFactory.newContentSource(uri)

def request = session.newModuleInvoke("ourQuery.xqy")
def criteria =
"""<criteria>
<equals>
<field>status</field>
<value>draft</value>
</equals>
</criteria>
"""

request.setNewVariable("criteria",ValueType.ELEMENT, criteria);

session.submitRequest(request).asString()
}
```

We are getting this error when executing:

> Caused by: com.marklogic.xcc.exceptions.XQueryException: XDMP-LEXVAL:
>   xs:QName("element()") -- Invalid lexical value "element()" [Session:
>   user=admin, cb={default} [ContentSource: user=admin, cb={none}
>   [provider: address=localhost/127.0.0.1:9001, pool=1/64]]] [Client:
>   XCC/5.0-3, Server: XDBC/5.0-3] expr: xs:QName("element()") at
>   com.marklogic.xcc.impl.handlers.ServerExceptionHandler.handleResponse(ServerExceptionHandler.java:34)
>   at
>   com.marklogic.xcc.impl.handlers.EvalRequestController.serverDialog(EvalRequestController.java:83)
>   at
>   com.marklogic.xcc.impl.handlers.AbstractRequestController.runRequest(AbstractRequestController.java:84)
>   at
>   com.marklogic.xcc.impl.SessionImpl.submitRequestInternal(SessionImpl.java:373)
>   at
>   com.marklogic.xcc.impl.SessionImpl.submitRequest(SessionImpl.java:356)
>   at
>   com.zynx.galen.dataaccess.MarkLogicUtilities.executeQueryWithMultipleXMLParameters(MarkLogicUtilities.groovy:52)
>   at
>   com.zynx.galen.repositories.ScopedInterventionService.getScopedInterventionsByCriteria(ScopedInterventionService.groovy:20)
>   ... 1 more

Any help would be greately appreciated.

Comment: Irina, are you sure the XQuery code is the same code that produced the error? The error message `XDMP-LEXVAL: xs:QName("element()") -- Invalid lexical value "element()"` looks like it would come from somewhere else entirely. Also is 8001 the right port? That would be very odd, since normally the Admin server is 8001.

Comment: Hi Michael, You are right the port is 9001 (I replaced the variables).If I change the code to accept a string variable the error goes away, so I am failry sure that it is the code producing the error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/xcc/overview-summary.html has the answer, I think:

> Passing Variables With Queries
>
> Variables may be bound to Request objects. When an execution request
>   is issued to the server with Session.submitRequest(Request) all the
>   variables currently bound to the Request object are sent along and
>   defined as external variables in the execution context in the server.
>
> XCC lets you create XdmNodes and XdmSequences, as well as XdmAtomic
>   values. However, in the initial XCC release values of this type may
>   not be bound as external variables because MarkLogic Server cannot yet
>   accept them. This capability is anticipated for a future release.

Since `XdmNode` is not supported, I suppose its subclass XdmElement is not supported either. So these classes are only useful for responses, not requests. The error message could stand to be improved.

You could pass the XML string using `setNewStringVariable`, then call `xdmp:unquote` in your XQuery module. Note that `xdmp:unquote` returns a document-node, so the `/*` XPath step yields its root element.

```
declare variable $xml-string as xs:string external ;
declare variable $criteria as element(criteria) := xdmp:unquote($xml-string)/* ;
....
```